# Q: How do I make each div fade away individually?

Tags: javascript

So I have JSON object and I have to make that each div fades away by the number of their age.

[The code so far](http://jsbin.com/rizivawiku/edit?css,js,output)!

**JS**

```
var osobe;
getText = function(url, callback) // How can I use this callback?
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
        {
            callback(request.responseText); // Another callback here
        }
    }; 
    request.open('GET', url,true);
    request.send();
}

function mycallback(data) {
   osobe = JSON.parse(data).people;
  anim();
}

getText('http://output.jsbin.com/vawamasaci.json', mycallback);


function anim() {

  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.id = 'container';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(container);

  for(var key in osobe) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = osobe[key].name + "<br />";
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + osobe[key].sex;
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);

    var dob_split = osobe[key].dob.split("-");
    var yearOfBirth = dob_split[2];
    var age = new Date().getFullYear() - yearOfBirth;

    animBox(div, age);

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
  }

  function animBox(div, age){

    var int = setInterval(function() {

      var opacity = div.style.opacity;

      if(opacity != "0") {     
        div.style.opacity = opacity ? (parseFloat(opacity) - 0.1) : 1;
      }

   }, 1000);

   setTimeout(function(){ 

      clearInterval(int);

   }, age * 1000);

  }

}
```

**CSS**

```
#container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Using some form of ID would be one thing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function animBox(div, age){

   setTimeout(function(){ 

         var int = setInterval(function() {

      var opacity = div.style.opacity;

      if(opacity != "0") {     
        div.style.opacity = opacity ? (parseFloat(opacity) - 0.1) : 1;
      }

     }, 100);
   }, age * 100);

  }
```

}

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: tried in http://jsbin.com/qiwalerehe/edit?css,js,output and it worked

Comment: most welcome :)

Comment: would u plz mark my answer as correct cause I am trying to get some more points to earn some badges. :)